# Access Variable from within [ngClass] for conditional comparison

Tags: angular

I am trying to write a ticker/summary component for a sports website.
A fixture has a list of events (scores, sanctions, substitutions) that happen in that match and I want to display them in boxes that are either left or right aligned, depending on whether the home team or the visitor team is responsible for the event.

For this I am trying to assign a `left` or `right` class. What I have tried is:

```html
<div class="ticker" *ngFor="let event of events" [ngClass]="(event.team.teamName == {{fixture.homeTeam.teamName}})?'left':'right'"> 
    <!--content-->
</div>
```

But Angular does not allow Interpolation where I have tried to use it in `[ngClass]`.

How would I compare the `event.team.teamName` with the teamname from the component class variable `fixture: Fixture;`?

Comment: `(event.team.teamName === fixture.homeTeam.teamName) ? 'left' : 'right'"` does not work?

Comment: You can't mix binded properties with [] and {{}}. Maybe try event.team.teamName == fixture.homeTeam.teamName?

Comment: This will result in the following error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'teamName' of undefined`. But the element isn't undefined. I can access it's features just fine when I'm not using the [ngClass].

Comment: When is the teamName initialized?  If the data for fixture isn't available when the DOM is rendered, you'll get that error.  Try initializing fixture = {}; fixture.homeTeam={}; in the constructor.

Comment: How about writing the logic inside the component class as a function instead, something like getTickerPosition() and use it in [ngClass]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  [ngClass]="event?.team?.teamName === fixture?.homeTeam?.teamName ? 'left' : right'"
```

Comment: This solution has worked, thank you. I do not quite understand what the question marks do. Can you refer me to the corresponding chapter in the docs?